# Props error problem saying it is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-props, kakao

Kakao is also using the API.
Now I keep getting an error saying that onSelectLocation is not a function, but I really don't know.
Pass the onSelectLocation function from the parent component to the map component.
The map component renders addresses and coordinates.

I don't understand why onSelectLocation is not a function.
I asked gpt as well, but I couldn't find the answer I wanted.
Even when outputting through console.log, I confirmed that props were delivered properly, not unfind.

Error Text

ERROR
onSelectLocation is not a function
TypeError: onSelectLocation is not a function
at http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2926:11
at http://t1.daumcdn.net/mapjsapi/js/libs/services/1.0.2/services.js:6:1700
at Object.oncomplete (http://t1.daumcdn.net/mapjsapi/js/libs/services/1.0.2/services.js:6:194)

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/* global kakao */
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // prop-types 라이브러리를 import
// import InviteWritePage from '../pages/InviteWritePage';
const { kakao } = window;

function MapKakao({ onSelectLocation }) {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // 카카오 지도 초기화
    const container = document.getElementById('map');
    const options = { center: new kakao.maps.LatLng(33.450701, 126.570667) };
    const map = new kakao.maps.Map(container, options);
    setMap(map);

    // 장소 검색 객체 생성
    const geocoder = new kakao.maps.services.Geocoder();

    // 검색 버튼 클릭 이벤트 핸들러
    const searchButton = document.getElementById('search-button');
    searchButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // 입력된 주소 가져오기
      const input = document.getElementById('address-input');
      const address = input.value;

      // 주소를 검색하여 좌표를 얻어옴
      geocoder.addressSearch(address, (result, status) => {
        if (status === window.kakao.maps.services.Status.OK) {
          const latlng = new window.kakao.maps.LatLng(result[0].y, result[0].x);

          // 이전 마커가 있으면 제거
          if (map.marker) {
            map.marker.setMap(null);
          }

          // 새로운 마커 추가 및 지도 중심 이동
          const newMarker = new window.kakao.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
          });
          newMarker.setMap(map);
          map.panTo(latlng);

          // 위도, 경도, 주소 정보를 상위 컴포넌트로 전달
          onSelectLocation(latlng.getLat(), latlng.getLng(), address);
        } else {
          alert('주소를 찾을 수 없습니다.');
        }
      });
    });
  }, [onSelectLocation]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="address-input"
        placeholder="주소를 입력하세요"
        style={{ marginRight: '10px' }}
      />
      <button id="search-button">검색</button>
      <div id="map" style={{ height: '307px' }}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
MapKakao.propTypes = {
  onSelectLocation: PropTypes.func.isRequired, // onSelectLocation 프로퍼티를 정의하고 함수 형태로 검사합니다.
};
export default MapKakao;
```

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import MapKakao from '../services/MapKakao';

function InviteWritePage() {
  const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState({
    latitude: 0, // 초기값 설정
    longitude: 0, // 초기값 설정
    address: '', // 초기값 설정
  });

  // 사용자입력값 상태변수
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    title: '',
    date: '',
    body: '',
    category: '',
    totalNum: 0,
    money: 0,
    latitude: '',
    longitude: '',
    address: '',
  });

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // 서버로 보낼 데이터 생성
    // const requestData = {
    //   title: formData.title,
    //   date: formData.date,
    //   body: formData.body,
    //   category: formData.category,
    //   totalNum: formData.totalNum,
    //   money: formData.money,
    //   latitude: formData.latitude,
    //   longitude: formData.longitude,
    //   address: formData.address,
    // };

    const token = 
    // 서버로 POST 요청 보내기
    axios
      .post('http://3.39.76.109:8080/boards/new-boards', formData, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: token,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        // 성공적으로 생성되었을 때 처리할 로직
        console.log('Card created successfully:/', response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error creating card:', error);
      });
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevData) => ({
      ...prevData,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  // 사용자가 지도에서 선택한 장소 정보를 업데이트하는 함수
  const handleLocationSelect = (latitude, longitude, address) => {
    // console.log(latitude, longitude, address);
    setSelectedLocation({
      latitude,
      longitude,
      address,
    });
  };
  // console.log(handleLocationSelect);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Create a New Card</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Title:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="title"
            value={formData.title}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Date:
          <input
            type="date"
            name="date"
            value={formData.date}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Body:
          <textarea
            name="body"
            value={formData.body}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Category:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="category"
            value={formData.category}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Person:
          <input
            type="number"
            name="totalNum"
            value={formData.totalNum}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Money:
          <input
            type="number"
            name="money"
            value={formData.money}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label>
        {/* <label>
          address:
          <input
            type="text"
            name="address"
            // value={formData.address}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          />
        </label> */}
      </form>
      <MapKakao onSelectLocation={handleLocationSelect} />
      <p>선택한 주소: {selectedLocation.address}</p>
      <p>위도: {selectedLocation.latitude}</p>
      <p>경도: {selectedLocation.longitude}</p>
      <button type="submit">Create Card</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default InviteWritePage;
```

Comment: Maybe you use `<MapKakao` more than once?

Comment: @Konrad Yes, that's right. First of all, in the InviteWritePage component
The map has been rendered.
When I try to render Kakao Map in InvitePage, the above error appears!